# How to load html file into div element then use elements from that html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, jquery-callback

When I am loading html file into div element and then I am trying to  use elements from that html I can't find them. 
I am doing it in this way :

```
    var View = (function() {
        var instance = null;
        var IMG_ARROW_UP = "icon_arrow_up.png", IMG_ARROW_DOWN = "icon_arrow_down.png", IMG_ARROW_ACTIVE = "icon_arrow_right_active.png", IMG_ARROW_INACTIVE = "icon_arrow_right_inactive.png";
/**
 * DOM elements
 */
var container, menuArrowUp;
/**
 * DOM attributes
 */
var CONTAINER_ID = "container";

function init() {
    loadView();

    function loadView() {
        if (!DomHelper.nodeIsExist(CONTAINER_ID)) {
            DomHelper.createDivNode(document.body,
                    CONTAINER_ID, "");
            $("#" + CONTAINER_ID).load(
                    Properties.getParameter("template",
                            "VIEW_MARKUP"), function() {
                        initializeDomElements();
                        Manager.handleVisibility(CONTAINER_ID, false);
                    });
```

}
        }

```
    function initializeDomElements() {
        container = DomHelper
                .getByElementId(CONTAINER_ID);
        menuArrowUp = DomHelper
                .getByElementId("menuArrowUp");
    }

    function createViewHeader() {
        var headerNode = DomHelper.getByElementId("viewHeading");
        DomHelper.setNodeText(headerNode, getMessage("header"));
    }

    function setupImages() {
        DomHelper.setImageSrc(menuArrowUp, getImageSrc(IMG_ARROW_UP));
    }

    function getImageSrc(imagePath) {
        return DomHelper.getItemImage("IMAGES_PROPERTY", imagePath);
    }

    return {
        onShow : function() {
            Manager.handleVisibility(CONTAINER_ID, true);
            createViewHeader();
            setupImages();
        },

    }

}

return {
    getInstance : function() {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = init();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

})();

```
    //
    View.getInstance().onShow();
```

initializeDomElements() function should be called before onShow() function but in reality it calls after.

Comment: If only people didn't use random frameworks instead of the official DOM API, I'd be able to answer so many questions... What's DOMHelper...? Also, you tagged your question Jquery, where is JQuery used?

Comment: It's another function.  $("#" + CONTAINER_ID).load() it is jquery!

Comment: `"I am trying to use elements from that html I can't find them"` - You need to be more specific.  Where are you trying to use these elements?  How are you trying to find them?  Is the content loaded when that code executes?

Comment: I am trying to use then in onShow() method

Comment: @user3783844: Ok, and do those elements *exist* when you invoke that code?  According to the code posted, you're invoking that method *immediately*.  It isn't going to find elements which haven't actually been added to the page yet.  You would need to invoke it *after* the AJAX call is used to add the elements to the page.

Comment: Thanks David,I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Load the HTML using jQuery.

```
$('#yourElement').load('page.html', function() {
  /* When load is done */
}
```

Comment: $("#" + CONTAINER_ID).load(
                    Properties.getParameter("template",
                            "VIEW_MARKUP"), function() {
                        initializeDomElements();
                        Manager.handleVisibility(CONTAINER_ID, false);
                    });                                                                                                                     it is look likes the same :)